# Disable VS Code warning "submodules which won't be opened automatically"

Tags: visual-studio-code, warnings

Every time I open a repo with a lot of submodules on VS Code, I get a pop-up message like:

> The 'rust-devel' repository has 15 submodules which won't be opened automatically. You can still open each one individually by opening a file within.

Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: something similar happens stating "Error: EMFILE: too many open files" and it names the `.gitmodules` file. Solution below about `git.detectSubmodulesLimit` alleviates the issue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I didn't find a way to disable this warning. However there is a workaround: By increasing the `Git: Detect Submodules Limit` setting to a value higher than the number of submodules, the warning is not shown.

For example, this sets the limit to 30 via the VS Code settings.json file:

```
{
    "git.detectSubmodulesLimit": 30
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the best solution for the time being.

Comment: still valid in 2023

Answer (score 8):

edit settings.json:

```json
"git.detectSubmodules": false,
"git.detectSubmodulesLimit": 9999
```

The first one avoids the auto-detection, the second one gets rid of the warning. [credit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50165#issuecomment-390429536)  Probably best to set more reasonable in case 9999 may slow your machine. Couldn't seem to find any reasoning why the default is 10.

also [see vs code defaults](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```json
  // Controls whether to automatically detect git submodules.
  "git.detectSubmodules": true,

  // Controls the limit of git submodules detected.
  "git.detectSubmodulesLimit": 10,
```